# Same sub label with same subID in chemnum

Tags: chemistry, chemnum

I didn't find how to achieve this in the documentation or if it is even possible.

I know I could initialize all the sub labels every time, however, I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this automatically via some option. This could save me a lot of manual editing and introducing mistakes.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
\cmpd{educt.a},
\cmpd{educt.b},
\cmpd{educt.c},
```

returns **1a**, **1b**, **1c**

with

```
\cmpd{product.b},
\cmpd{product.c},
\cmpd{product.a},
```

returning **2b**, **2c**, **2a**

currently I get **2a**, **2b**, **2c** instead (which can be confusing, as usually same sublabel corresponds to the same substituents)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}
\cmpd{educt.a}
\cmpd{educt.b}
\cmpd{educt.c}

\cmpd{product.b},
\cmpd{product.c},
\cmpd{product.a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your minimal working example?

Comment: @Sebastiano I added it. Sorry, since the code is this dead simple I didn't think it was needed.

Comment: Daniel very good and thank you for your collaboration.